# Switch of branch with git checkout on Eclipse IDE points to wrong branch

Tags: eclipse, git, git-branch, branching-and-merging

Switch of branch with git checkout on Eclipse IDE points to wrong branch!.

I have 2 remote branches say by name 'qa_branch' & 'qa_rel_branch' created on top of master

So at point of above remote branch creation both points to same hash

When I `right click on repository & select ''Switch to'-> Other & select 'qa_branch' from 'Remote tracking branches'` it checks out & switches to 'qa_rel_branch'instead of 'qa_branch'

Plan is to block check-in/merge to *rel* branch & use only to diff out to do incremental release.

However command line run of below just works fine. Issue only in Eclipse IDE

`git checkout qa_branch`

Comment: If you switch to a remote branch, Eclipse offers you two possibilities: _Check out as New Local Branch_ and _Check out Commit_. What did you choose?

Comment: @howlger - Used `'Right click on repository' - > Switch to -> Other... -> Remote Tracking ( expand & select qa_branch from it )`

Comment: Yes, in the current version of Eclipse/EGit, a dialog box will appear after these steps (if you select a remote branch to check out). If you do not see the dialog that ask you _[Check out as New Local Branch]_, _[Check out Commit]_ or _[Cancel]_, I recommend to update EGit.

Comment: @howlger   - Yea, already using EGit plugin & with above followed steps is popping up window ` 'Checkout a ref or work with branches'` . From which I am looking to select 'qa_branch'under Remote Tracking option & hitting Çheckout' button in popped out window. This is what resulting in swithing to 'qa_rel_branch' instead of selected 'qa_branch

Comment: I'm talking not about the dialog where you select the remote branch. There will be another dialog with some text and three buttons (_[Check out as New Local Branch], [Check out Commit]_ and _[Cancel]_) only. Which EGit version do you use? In Git you can not work on a remote branch. Normally, you check out a new local branch which can have the same name or a different name. Can you show a screenshot that shows all your remote and local branches after you did the switch?

Comment: I am afraid, it's pretty old version eGit 2.1 :( . Will follow up with central team to get update - unfortunately don't have provision to get snapshot to show here..